# Excel Function: How often does X fit in Y

Tags: microsoft-excel

It's been years since I used that function but I know it exists but I just don't know what it is called.
What the function does is it would tell you how often a number can fit into another one. Basically a round up of something like 36 / 5 which would result in 7,2 as a normal calculation and result in 7 if used with that function. It is very handy for some cases and yet I don't know what it's called.

Does anyone know about this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at QUOTIENT. It will return the integer portion of a division.

Comment: Yup that's the solution. I honestly would not have found it since I'm not familiar with the word integer except for some programming languages. Thanks very much.

Comment: @VarmintLP feel free to press the check mark next to this answer so others know you no longer need help. :)

Comment: I thought I did it already but it was not properly visible due to the dark mode plugin. :)
Have your well earned points.